# Angluar client cant resolve json from spring boot because of cors error

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, http, cors

I want to create an angular client, which querys some json from a localhost spring boot server.
my HTTP Angluar service looks so:

```
export class ProductService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/priceoffer24/api/product';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getProductById(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/products/${id}`);
  }

  public getProductByName(name: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/products/${name}`);
  }
  public getProductByBrand(brand: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/products/brand/${brand}`);
  }

  public getProductsList(): Observable<any>  {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/products`);
  }

  public getProductsNewest(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/products/newest`);
  }

  public getProductsRandom(): any {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/products/random`);
  }

  public getProductsBySubcategorie(subcategorie: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/products/subcategorie/${subcategorie}`);
  }

  public getProductsBySubcategorieId(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/products/subcategorie/${id}`);
  }

  public getProductsByCategorie(categorie: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/products/categorie/${categorie}`);
  }

  public getProductsByCategorieId(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/products/categorie/${id}`);
  }

  public getProductsBySubcategorieAndCategorie(subcategorie: string, categorie: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/products/subcategorie/${subcategorie}/categorie/${categorie}`);
  }

}
```

My problem is now that I get the following cors error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/priceoffer24/api/product/products/newest' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What do I have to change in my angular app, or in my spiring boot app ?

Comment: You’ll need to enable CORS in your spring boot app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://example.com")` over your spring boot rest controller.

Here **`http://example.com`** refers to angular app URL (Client App). Doing this will allow only the particular application to access your application.

If you want to allow all hosts to access your controller then just use `@CrossOrigin` directly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't in the Angular App, you have to add your client app URL (default should be http://localhost:4200) to the Allowed Origins in the Api Server (spring boot).

So to resolve this just search how to fix the server side.
Probably this can help https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/